# Use of SQL Server's Stop Lists

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search

2 Questions:

1 - How does stop lists improve fulltext query performance in SQL Server 2008 (or it does not)? Is it a good idea to have stop lists assign to all catalogs?

2 - When a catalog uses stop lists, how can a query like this one work? SQL Server is searching for the stop word "of" and it finds all results correctly.

```
SELECT * 
from Table
where CONTAINS(Text,'"performance of"') --- "of" is a stop word.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How does stop lists improve fulltext query performance in SQL Server 2008 (or it does not)?

Stop lists are not there for performance reasons. They are there to avoid searches containing words like "the" from matching huge numbers of records, which would just make the results meaningless.

> When a catalog uses stop lists, how can a query like this one work? SQL Server is searching for the stop word "of" and it finds all results correctly.

A stop list word is just ignored - it doesn't cause the query to fail. The word "performance" is not in the stop list so fields containing this word are found.